# How to load a view when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a list of buttons in my `<div>`, when the user click on a specific div, I want display a view of my controller, for example:

```
<div class="row">
      <div id="booking" class="command-buttons tile col-xs-12 btn">
            <h3 class="title">Book appointment</h3>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I want load the appointment booking page when my user click on `booking` div. For load a view I use this code:

```
$this->load->view('appointments/book', $view);
```

but how I can do this using js? Usually a call a function that contains the view load, but in this case I'm on js side.

Comment: you can't load views externally. instead on you can load views internally on your controllers.. the max what u can do is redirect on click.

Comment: Why a div? Links and buttons are designed for clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

probably something like that:

```
$('div#booking').on('click', function() {
    $(this).load( "view.html");
});
```

you can find some details here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think

```
echo $this->load->view('appointments/book', $view, true);
```

will return the html to your ajax success function and you can then easily inject it in the page.